# Azure B2C MFA Call option

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to implement MFA phone call support. I have set the meta-data to use "mixed"

```
 <TechnicalProfile Id="PhoneFactor-Verify">
          <DisplayName>PhoneFactor</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.PhoneFactorProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.phonefactor</Item>
            <Item Key="ManualPhoneNumberEntryAllowed">false</Item>
            <Item Key="setting.authenticationMode">mixed</Item>
          </Metadata>
```

but I still see sms option. The technical profile which DisplayControl calls is as follows:

```
 <TechnicalProfile Id="AzureMfa-SendSmsSimple">
          <DisplayName>Send Sms</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.AzureMfaProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">OneWaySMS</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
```

I am guessing, I need to create a new "ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile" which will reference a new "TechnicalProfile" with **operation** for call or something, but I dont see that in any documentation. Can someone pls share a sample or documentation link to create operation for call.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Displaycontrol doesn’t support call option. You have to call phonefactor technical profile directly from user journey as per the B2C starter pack.

Comment: Thanks, but I am little confused on how will it trigger. As of now, Display control shows a button to send SMS, how can I integrate call me button there? and will it work like: display control cancels SMS send code and User-Journey's next step will use some claim to call "PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify"

Comment: You either use displaycontrol with just sms, *or* phonefactor with sms and/or call options.